# Accessing array indices using a macro in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to access a C array using a macro. The array is declared as extern const in a header file and actually defined/initialized in a source file. The macro is in the header. I then want to access the array from another file. Both the other file and the file that defines the array #include the header.

I've tried accessing the array directly from the other file and it works. I can also successfully use the macro if the array is defined in the header instead of a separate C file. But I need to access the array using a macro, and have the array defined in a separate source file, not the header.

This is what I have in the header (let's call it file.h):

```
#define SIZE 10

#define get_arr(i)     (arr[i])

extern const uint8 arr[SIZE];
```

In the source with the array definition (this is file.c):

```
"#include file.h"

const uint8 arr[SIZE] = {0};
```

In the other source file that actually wants to use the array:

```
"#include file.h"

for(uint8 i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
   Data[i] = get_arr(i); //Data is a pointer passed as a parameter to a function)
}
```

When I try to build, I get a problem with linking: "unresolved symbols".

Comment: Please place quotes around your include and/or include real code.  Also include which symbol was unresolved.  Finally, make sure that all your source files are indeed linked together so that the files can see each other's globals.

Comment: Post the command line(s) that you used to compile the program.

Comment: Where do you define Data  ? (I see Data[i] in the for loop, but not a declaration).

Comment: His comment says it was passed as a function parameter.  Fully compiling code would help with these problems though...

Comment: what is/are the unresolved symbol(s)  ? Do you link all the needed objects or you missed file.o (whatever the way to give it, may be only one command to compile and link all)

Comment: `#define get_arr(i)     (arr[i])` just obfuscates what the code does.  `get_arr( i )` doesn't provide any advantages over directly using `arr` with `arr[ i ]`, but it hides the use of the actual variable.

Comment: @moona did you read my answer ? Look in your makefile how the executable is made and you will see _file.o_ is missing in the link

Answer (score 2):

> I get a problem with linking: "unresolved symbols".

if the unresolved symbols concern *arr* that means you missed to link with *file.o*

For instance having :

file.h

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

typedef unsigned char uint8;

#define SIZE 10

#define get_arr(i)     (arr[i])

extern const uint8 arr[SIZE];

#endif
```

file.c

```
#include "file.h"

const uint8 arr[SIZE] = {0};
```

main.c

```
#include "file.h"

void fill(uint8 * Data)
{
  for(uint8 i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    Data[i] = get_arr(i); //Data is a pointer passed as a parameter to a function)
  }
}

int main()
{
  uint8 a[SIZE];
  fill(a);
}
```

If I compile and link all file there is no error whatever the way :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc file.c main.c 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

or

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -c main.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -c file.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc main.o file.o
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

etc

But if I miss to link with file.o :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc main.c
/tmp/ccG9WO0e.o : Dans la fonction « fill » :
main.c:(.text+0x60) : référence indéfinie vers « arr »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

or

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -c main.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -c file.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc main.o
main.o : Dans la fonction « fill » :
main.c:(.text+0x60) : référence indéfinie vers « arr »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

etc